# Visual Studio 2010 and Clickonce: old .NET and office prerequisites

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment, ms-office, clickonce

I am currently preparing an application in Visual Basic, mostly targeted on systems with .NET 2 installed and office 2003.

Moreover, as the systems are corporate ones, they need administrstion rights, so I had in mind an app that does not need to install anything (or register).

The application uses an external ocx, an axwebbrowser ocx and an excel interop.

The first problem stands because a user cannot run the application as it crashes, seeming because cannot find on his system ahdocvw.dll. is there a way to install for example a redistr package that includes the axwebbrowser system xomponent? At least to append it on the clickonce setup.

Second, in case that the user does not have the required framework, I would like to add on the Clickonce prerequisite box, the option for .NET 2 and office 2003. Right now, VS 2010 has only available .NET 3.5+ and Office Pia 2007.... could you suggest to me on how to proceed?